# Build index page from custom fields

Tags: custom-field, wpdb

Im starting to delve deeper into Wordpress custom fields and wanting to replicate this page in Wordpress:
http://www.clubsact.com.au/corporate/index.php

So my site is not tightly structured to a parent/child relationship, I have created a custom field 'Partner_Level' and based on the partner level entered by the author the function will write out the Feature Image associated with the post and create my index page.

Though I cant even seem to get my query working within a function. If I follow the instructions on this page:
http://css-tricks.com/snippets/wordpress/custom-loop-based-on-custom-fields/ writing straight to my template, all is good. So Im assuming I don't have something configured correctly, but at a lose as to what.

Functions.php

```
function the_partners($cpLevel) {
// This query grabs all fields with Metadata, matches 
 $querydetails = "
   SELECT wposts.*
   FROM $wpdb->posts wposts, $wpdb->postmeta wpostmeta
   WHERE wposts.ID = wpostmeta.post_id
   AND wpostmeta.meta_key = 'Partner_Level'
   AND wpostmeta.meta_value = '$cpLevel'
   AND wposts.post_status = 'publish'
   AND wposts.post_type = 'page'
   ORDER BY wposts.post_date DESC
 "; 

$pageposts = $wpdb->get_results($querydetails, OBJECT);

if ($pageposts) {
    echo "Got em";
}
}
```

page_corp.php

```
if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post();
<h1><?php the_title(); ?></h1>

the_partners('Gold');
endwhile; endif;
```

In the page, Im simply expecting "Got em" to be printed to the screen, though Im getting a blank.

Cheers,

Phil

Answer (score 2):

my suggesting is going for a different way by using get_pages()

for example

```
$args = array(
         'meta_key ' => 'Partner_Level',
         'meta_value' => 'Gold' );
$pageslist = get_pages( $args );
```

$pageslist should have all your posts in the "gold" level.

Comment: Thanks for that Peter, I will check that out...

I also placed global $wpdb; inside of my function and that worked.

By using the get_posts() is that going to be efficient? Could I also pass a query to get the post_thumbnails for the posts?

Comment: get_posts() is the prefered way to fetch posts. and sure, every works fine as usual in your Loop.

Comment: Thanks Peter, I got it working through get_posts... Though its returning all pages in the sites, not only the ones with the Partner Level of Gold.

Comment: $args = array(
 'meta_query' => array(
      array(
  'meta_key' => 'Partner_Level',
  'meta_value' => 'Gold' ),
  'post_type' => 'page',
  'post_status' => 'publish' ));
  $pages = get_pages( $args );
 
 var_dump($pages);

Comment: oh my bad, i didn't notice the post_type. i've updated my answer. get_pages() has different parameters, namely the meta_query.

Comment: Not a worry at all, I was reviewing the WPCodex and just passed in post_type = page and it retrieved pages.

Though what is happening is its not jumping into the custom field that I have set up. So the query is simply pulling out every page, not the pages that have the Partner_Level of Gold.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up coming back to my original approach.

Adding  global $wpdb; in my function, I was able to retrieve the information that I needed to.

Everything is working now.. Hope this helps others.